# PostgreSQL - Simulate for-loop and aggregation with SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a SQL table similar to this one

```
ID  |   COL1    |   COL2    |   SIM
=======================================
1   |   A       |   B       |   5
2   |   Z       |   A       |   3
3   |   C       |   B       |   3.5
4   |   B       |   Z       |   0.5
5   |   C       |   Z       |   1.1
```

I'm trying to create a query, that for each unique value in `COL1` **OR** `COL2` will aggregate the values in the corresponding `COL` column, along with the `SIM` values.
Desired output:

```
ID  |   AGG_KEY     |   AGG_IDS     |   AGG_SIM
========================================================
1   |   A           |   [B, Z]      |   [5, 3]
2   |   B           |   [A, C, Z]   |   [5, 3.5, 0.5]
3   |   C           |   [B, Z]      |   [3.5, 1.1]
4   |   Z           |   [A, B, C]   |   [3, 0.5, 1.1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . if I understand correctly, you can "unpivot" and aggregate:

```
select v.cola, array_agg(v.colb order by t.sim desc), array_agg(t.sim order by t.sim desc)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (col1, col2), (col2, col1)) v(cola, colb)
group by v.cola;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7b43bf065a48058f9bf69493ae1aad64) is a db<>fiddle.